# MediaPlugin - Get MediaFile From Path

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This may be a simple question but I can't get it to work.
I have no issue setting a picture from the Camera with TakePhotoAsync().

The problem is that I upload the pictures to a BlobStorage and I would like to get a Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile from the blob Byte array.
Something like :

```
MediaFile file = new MediaFile(...);
```

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanks in advance

EDIT : My question seems to be not clear enough based on an answer.
I am able to take a picture and upload it to a blob storage.

It is the opposite that I want to do and don't see how.
I want to download the picture from the Blob storage which I get as a byte array and then get a MediaFile from it.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to take image using this code:

```
EventImageFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
                        new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                        {
                            SaveToAlbum = true,
                            Directory = "your directory name",
                            Name = DateTime.Now + ".jpg",
                            DefaultCamera = CameraDevice.Rear,
                            //CompressionQuality = 10
                        });
```

Then you can convert it to byte[] using this piece of code:

```
private byte[] ConvertMediaFileToByteArray(MediaFile file)
{
    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
        return memoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}
```

And post your byte[] to blob storage

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
As I said, I have no issue getting and uploading the file from the TakePhotoAsync.
My issue is that the I want to download the picture bytes from the blob storage and then instantiate a MediaFile with the byte array.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. Did you try:                              ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

Comment: I can do that too and it works like a charm.
However I still cannot see how to get a Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaFile.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by providing a `Func` which returns a stream for your byte array:

```
var image = new MediaFile("C:\fake-blob-filename.jpg", () =>
            {
                new MemoryStream(blobBytes); // Your byte array is the argument
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

To download the image from blob use HttpClient and download it as Byte array. 
Once you have your array you can save it to any folder your app has permissions. 
When you save it you should have the path for the same.
You can use the path to load the image via Image view or via Media Picker.

Comment: I think that is what I will end up doing. 
I was looking for a way to avoid that but I'm not sure that is possible.
Thanks.